# How to paginate long lists

Tags: perl, catalyst, pagination, paginator

I am (still) learning the Catalyst Framework for Perl. And I need to paginate a long list of books. What I do not know what to use to paginate and how to used it. Second, if I want to pass a "page=1" parameter to my list method (in it form now) the passed value doesn't apper. If I modify the number of Args to 1, then it complains that it can not find the page.

These are my files:

**Book.pm** (the ORM file)

```
use utf8;
package Library::Schema::Result::Books;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Core';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("InflateColumn::DateTime");
__PACKAGE__->table("books");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  {
    data_type => "uuid",
    default_value => \"uuid_generate_v4()",
    is_nullable => 0,
    size => 16,
  },
  "title",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 128 },
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");
__PACKAGE__->add_unique_constraint("uk_books", ["title"]);
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

**Book.pm** (the controller)

```
package Library::Controller::Book;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use utf8;
use Data::Validate::UUID qw(is_uuid);

BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller'; }

sub base :Chained('/'): PathPart('book'): CaptureArgs(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->stash(books_rs => $c->model('DB::Books'));
    $c->stash(books => [$c->stash->{books_rs}->search(
        {},
        {order_by => 'title ASC'})]
    );
}

sub list :Chained('base'): PathPart('list'): Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->stash(template => 'book/list.tt2');
}

sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    return $c->res->redirect(
        $c->uri_for($c->controller('Book')->action_for('list'))
    );
}

sub book :Chained('base'): PathPart(''): CaptureArgs(1) {
    my ($self, $c, $bookid) = @_;
    if(!is_uuid(uc($bookid))) {
        die "Invalid book ID.";
    }
    my $book = $c->stash->{books_rs}->find(
        { id => $bookid },
        { key => 'primary' }
    );
    die "No such user" if(!$book);
    $c->stash(book => $book);
}

sub add :Chained('base'): PathPart('add'): Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    if(lc $c->req->method eq 'post') {
        my $params = $c->req->params;
        my $books_rs = $c->stash->{books_rs};
        my $newbook = $books_rs->create({
            title => $params->{newBookTitle},
        });
        return $c->res->redirect(
            $c->uri_for($c->controller('Book')->action_for('list')
        ));
    }
}

sub edit :Chained('book') :PathPart('edit'): Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    if(lc $c->req->method eq 'post') {
        my $params = $c->req->params;
        my $book = $c->stash->{book};
        $book->update({
            title => $params->{title},
        });
        return $c->res->redirect( $c->uri_for(
            $c->controller('Book')->action_for('list'),
            [ $book->id ]
        ));
    }
}

sub remove :Chained('book'): PathPart('remove'): Args() {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    my $book = $c->stash->{book};
    $book->delete();
    return $c->res->redirect(
        $c->uri_for($c->controller('Book')->action_for('list'))
    );
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

and the relevant part on my **books/list.tt** file:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Book title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        [% FOREACH book IN books -%]
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="[%- c.uri_for(c.controller('Book').action_for('remove'), [book.id]) %]">
                    <img src="../../images/trash.png" width="22" height="22">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>[% book.title %]</td>
        </tr>
        [% END -%]
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you want an URL `example.org/list?page=1`, right? There's no `book` in there, and we are talking about an URL parameter, not a path parameter like `example.org/list/1`. Is your question more about how to get the parameter into Catalyst, or about making DBIC do the pagination for you? It looks like you've done neither yet.

Comment: The DBIC pagination is what I want to implement here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do to get this to work. Overall, it's quite straight-forward. It's described in the [DBIC Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Paged-results).

### Controller

Your `list` method as it is only lists the full unpaginated list of books, which was stashed in your `base` chained method. You now need to add code to take an URL parameter and reduce the list.

```
sub list :Chained('base'): PathPart('list'): Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;

    if (my $page = $c->req->params->{page}) {
        # TODO: validate $page

        my $rs = $c->stash->{books};
        $c->stash->{books} = $rs->search(undef, {
             page => $page,
             rows => 10,    # or how many you want
        });
    }

    $c->stash(template => 'book/list.tt2');
}
```

This code will replace your stashed resultset with a new one, that's got a `LIMIT` attached to it. Remember that resultsets can chain to stack, so with every new `->search` you call one a resultset object, a new one that's further drilled down is returned. No SQL is run until later in your template, where you use it in list context, which implies a call to `->all`.

There is no need to make any changes to the template for displaying the smaller list.

However, you probably want to control your pagination. You can do that with a [Data::Page](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Page) object. Your resultset conveniently provides this for you. However, this comes at the cost of an additional `COUNT` query. Turn on the `DBIC_TRACE=1` environment variable to take a look at the queries run in the background if you are interested in what's happening.

In your `list` method, where we just added the above code, stash the pager as well.

```
my $rs = $c->stash->{books};
$c->stash->{books} = $rs->search(undef, {
     page => $page,
     rows => 10,    # or how many you want
});

$c->stash->{pager} = $rs->pager;
```

### Template

Now we need to display some controls in the template. I'll not show all of them, but only give you an idea. Since we are still supporting a full list, we can only show the controls if there is a pager.

```
<table>
    [%# ... %]
    <tbody>
        [% FOREACH book IN books -%]
        <tr>
            [%# ... %]
        </tr>
        [% END -%]
    </tbody>
</table>

[% IF pager %]
<ul>
    <li><a href="?page=[% pager.first_page %]">First page</a></li>
</ul>
[% END %]
```

There's no need to use `c.uri_for` here, because all we do is add an URL parameter. The user's browser is smart enough to make this relative URL with only params point at the same thing it was already on. So if the user is viewing `https://example.org/list?page=2`, clicking the *First page* link `?page=1` will actually take them to `https://example.org/list?page=1`.

Comment: It complains, telling me that it can not create pager for a non-paged rs.

Comment: @KérdezösködőIndián it should be paged once it has the `page` attribute in it. Strange. I couldn't actually run this code, so this is just from the docs. You might need to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of that non-paged error:

```
sub list :Chained('base'): PathPart('list'): Args(0) {
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    if (my $page = $c->req->params->{page}) {
        my $rs = $c->stash->{books_rs}->search({}, {
             page => $page,
             rows => 5,
        });
        $c->stash->{books_rs} = $rs;
        $c->stash->{pager} = $rs->pager;
    }
    $c->stash(template => 'book/list.tt2');
}
```

but it still displays all the books. The value passed using the **page** parameter has no effect on the result set.